# Validation Constraint, optional field in DTO?

Tags: java, javax.validation

I have a DTO with a couple fields, username, password and email All of them Strings.

I also have a List that I want as an optional, meaning it does not have to be passed in from the form and can be left blank.

This should be valid from the front-end:

```
{
"username":"user",
"email":"email@email.com",
"password": "123",
"hobbies":[ "Weightlifting", "Dancing"]
}
```

So should this:

```
{
"username":"user",
"email":"email@email.com",
"password": "123"
}
```

Is there any @OptionalField annotation or the likes within javax.validation.constraints?

Or is my only option two seperate DTOs?

Comment: If you don't want hobbies list so add @transient annotation.if you use this annotation that particular field is not participate in serialization.

Comment: use `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"properties to ignore"})` on your DTO

Comment: These comments don't appear to make the field optional, that appear to make it ignored.    I think the question (certainly my question) is how to have a DTO with an _optional_ field.   At the moment we are confronted with sending one of two different DTOs depending on whether we have the optional field data or not.

Comment: I think you are using same DTO for 2 purposes or APIs? In one the list is mandatory and in another is not?

Answer (score 0):

Solution in this case was to make the field an Optional. Example, `Optional<Set<Hobby>> hobbies;`